# Add onchange to input inside template yii2 fileInput

Tags: php, yii2

I am using file upload in yii2 with default yii2 fileInput().
The code is:

```
$form->field($model, 'image', [
       'template' => "<span class='button'>{input}Browse</span><input type='text' placeholder='Include some files' readonly=''>"
       ])->fileInput(['multiple' => false, 'accept' => 'image/* '])->label(false);
```

Here I use custom template as above. The problem is that {input} generates input field automatically, but I want to add an onchange attribute to this input. Is it possible? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi, what exactly do you want to do with `onChange` event? Is it related to viewing this field or something different? Could you please give me some more information?

Comment: I want to change value of another field on onchange.

Comment: I understand. I'm not sure about which `onChange` event you meant (file/field/value change?), so I wrote according to first detected event with the same name. I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to change whatever you want, however, a more reliable and faster way is to use [FileInput Widget by Kartik](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput). You'll have to install it first. To do that, write this command in composer or bash command line: `composer require "kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput": "*"` and after install don't forget to **use** it by writing `use kartik\file\FileInput;` in your project .php file.

Then you can see [all possible plugin events](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#events) (there are quite a lot of them). The first event described in there is **change** *("This event is triggered whenever a single file or multiple files are selected in the file input via the file browse button")*.

To initialize a plugin event, use something like this:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'attribute', [
    'template' => "<span class='button'>{input}Browse</span><input type='text' placeholder='Include some files' readonly=''>"])->widget(FileInput::classname(),
     [
        'options' => ['multiple' => false, 'accept' => 'image/*'],
        'pluginEvents' => [
            'change' => 'function(event) {
                alert("File changed");
            }'
        ]
    ])->label(false);
```

Now you can write your JavaScript/jQuery Closure fuction in those lines where `alert("File changed");` is located. It is recommended since it provides you with sufficient options to choose from and much faster development.

Comment: 'pluginEvents' => , missed the '>' character. By the way, it works! thx

Comment: added back the missing greater than sign. Sorry I forgot to comment on the edit. Commented here instead.